# Is there a way for an Activity to know what fragment was just created?

Tags: android

An `Activity` may inflate an arbitrary layout xml that may or may not have a `Fragment` placeholder in it.

If it does , the `Fragment` will be instantiated and attached to the `Activity`.

Is there any way to get a reference to the `Fragment` from the `Activity` that has been attached to it ?

`FragmentManger.findFragmentById()` assumes you know the ID in advance to make it work but in this situation I am proposing, it is not available.

The behavior I'd ideally like to have is that the `Activity` is aware of any `Fragment`s attaching itself to it so that it may respond to it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Whenever a fragment is attached to an activity the following callback method is called with the fragment attached as the parameter, you can use it store the reference.

```
onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onAttachFragment(android.app.Fragment)

Comment: damn, onAttachFragment tells you when the fragment is attached but it does not tell you when it's ready to be worked with i.e. post fragment.onActivityCreated()

Comment: for that you can have a callback in your fragment like an interface inside the fragment implemented by your activity... so when the fragment is ready you can call the callback... For using this you can set the reference for the activity in onAttachFragment... this might also help

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity