# kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException at com.example.myapplication.ui.home.HomeFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I'm trying to manipulate elements from xml of a fragment, but all tries I did, result in some error. When I use root!!.qr_code.visibility = View.INVISIBLE, I got this:

What is wrong with my elements reference?

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.test, PID: 26445
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
> Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
> at com.example.myapplication.ui.home.HomeFragment.setElementVisibility(HomeFragment.kt:49)
> at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:72)

**My HomeFragment: (called from onCreate in MainActivity)**

```
package com.example.myapplication.ui.home

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import com.example.myapplication.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.view.*

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel
    private var root: View? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        //The findViewById appears as unresolved reference.
        qrcode = findViewById(R.id.qr_code) as LinearLayout

        return root

    }

    fun setElementVisibility(permissionData: Boolean, serialData: Boolean){
        //also I tried: 
        //qr_code.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        //which gives me the same error from above
        if(!serialData){
            root!!.qr_code.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            root!!.failed_layout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            root!!.success_layout.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        } else if(!permissionData){
            root!!.qr_code.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            root!!.failed_layout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            root!!.success_layout.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        } else if(permissionData && serialData){
            root!!.qr_code.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            root!!.failed_layout.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            root!!.success_layout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity call to HomeFragment:**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.nav_home), drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)



        val homeFragment: HomeFragment = HomeFragment()
        homeFragment.setElementVisibility(true, true)//this parameters won't be statics
     
    }
```

**My xml of fragment:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/success_layout"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginVertical="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/success_msg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:ems="8"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/success_msg"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/failed_layout"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginVertical="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/failed_msg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:ems="8"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/failed_msg"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_error"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/qr_code"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginVertical="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/openScanner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/take_scan_qr_code" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Does plugin `kotlin-android-extensions` applied at build.gradle ?

Comment: @StanislavBondar yes

Comment: Plz provide code of  `setElementVisibility()` usage at `onCreate()`

Comment: @StanislavBondar done, I also update the ```setElementVisibility()``` function

Answer (score 2):

`findViewById()`is a method of the `View` object.

Try this :

```kotlin
qrcode = root.findViewById(R.id.qr_code) as LinearLayout
```

Comment: Using it in method onCreateView from fragment, it works! But the same didn't happen when I call the setElementVisibility() from **MainActivity**

Comment: Yes, of course, because `root` in an inner variable. If you want to externalize the method, you have to deal with the fragment's view, ie `getView().findViewById()`

Comment: it is my problem and what I need! A way to externalize and call the function at `MainActivity` (preferably in `onCreate` method)

Answer (score 2):

try this a quick solution, more details at last

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_home) {
    
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setElementVisibility()
   
    }

    fun setElementVisibility(){
            
            qr_code.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
           failed_layout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            success_layout.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }
}
```

So u r getting unresolve reference because as answered by bruno findviewbyId() is applied to View object. so u can use his method.
In my method u will call the function only after the view is created i.e. onViewCreated(). so u can now call directly. I called the view in fragment constructor itself. This is short and easy.
Thanks for more go through documentation.

Comment: I need to call the function from MainActivity, cause I have some parameters depending from MainActivity

Comment: With your answer, now I realize that I'd need a call after the CreateView be triggered

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9338245/13927095 check if this helps you

Answer (score 1):

You can't just init  `val homeFragment: HomeFragment = HomeFragment()` and access it's view from `Activity`. You need to attach `Fragment` to activity. This is official [example](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) of usage and integration of fragments

Comment: I read the official example, has too much theory, but bit of examples. I keep confuse, because in app, the fragment appears automatically (by template i chose) and I don't know yet where or how to attach

Comment: @AlexandreMartinsMontebelo if fragment appears automatically it's defined at `activity_main` layout. Any way you need to access it from `FragmentManager` like
 `supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById()`

Comment: Have you an idea how to "dissociate" the ```setupActionBarWithNavController``` function for instead do it more programatically? The fragment I need is inside the nav_host_fragment fragment